# How to optimize search restricted by boolean column?

Tags: optimization, sqlite, explain

I want to optimize a query<sup>1</sup> of the form

```
SELECT yid, xid FROM x WHERE is_principal;
```

Here, `is_principal` is a non-null boolean column of `x`.

If I run `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` on this query, the output I get is

```
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE x
```

I'd like to turn this `SCAN` into a `SEARCH`, so created the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX x_is_principal_idx ON x (is_principal);
```

...but it made no difference: the output of `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` remains unchanged.

Is there some other way to optimize this query?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> FWIW, this query is in fact a sub-query of a much larger query that I'm trying to optimize.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The expression `is_principal` is the same as `is_principal <> 0`, so the database assumes that *all* values except 0 are searched for, and estimates that most rows will match.

If the values in the `is_principal` column are proper booleans, you can get the database to assume a higher selectivity by searching for the value you actually want to search for:

```
SELECT yid, xid FROM x WHERE is_principal = 1
```

This query is likely to read the rows from the table in index order (i.e., random order), so if there is a large number of matching rows, performance will be worse.